# Working with Object() between files Python

Tags: python, object, queue

Situation: Given that I have a `queueA` declared in `fileA`,

```
fileA.py
end_queue = Object()
queueA = Queue.queue()

   queueA
| value123  | <-- front of the queue
| value234  |
| value345  |
| value456  | <-- final value put into queue
| end_queue | <-- end_queue object to denote the end of queue
```

in `fileB`,

```
import fileA

while True:
    string = fileA.queueA.get()

    if string is end_queue:
        break

    #rest of the code...
```

Problem: The above code produces the following error:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, object found
```

Question: I do know that this means I am trying to do a string/buffer operation on an `Object()` object. However, how do I check if the input is an `Object()` or `end_queue`.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't throw that exception. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Wish isinstance(object, classinfo) in python can help you.